# How to load and use external libraries in a component?

Tags: php, development, joomla-3.4

I am wondering how to load "external" php-libraries into my component.

I would like to fetch mail via imap. To get this working, I would like to use a lib which is able to handle smime-encoded mails.

I got my installer-script working -- it uploads the library to /lib/phpimap.

How can I include this in my component without changing the way the library is written?

As far as I understand, I could use `JLoader::discover` to do this.

However, if I use:

```
JLoader::discover('PhpImap', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/phpimap');
```

it would "detect" only classes in /lib/phpimap which begin with "PhpImap" - but the classes are named in another way and without any kind of a standard-prefix.

How can I solve that?

Comment: As you hace noticed Joomla Loader works in a Joomla way, then you have to provide you J classes to load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you hace noticed Joomla Loader works in a Joomla way, then you have to provide you J classes to load it.

So, the answer is: just include the library in the same way than it is shown in its examples. A best practice is to create J classes to encapsulate the library calls.

JLoader::discover follows a naming protocol, but JLoader::register allows to register and auto-load specific classes:

```
JLoader::register('MyClass', .... . '/myclass.php');
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. So I would not use JLoader::discover but jimport? Or do I really use include("/path/to/my/lib/test.php") ?

Comment: You can include specific classes with JLoader::register('MyClass', .... . '/myclass.php');

Comment: Hm okay - unfortunately this does not work at the moment. I got the following setup: http://d.pr/BrvD

But I always get the return: Class "Mailbox" not found :-(

Comment: You have namespaced the Class, then the name of the class (from outside the namespace) is PhpImap\Mailbox. Joomla Loader is compatible with PHP 5.3, a PHP version where there is no namespace support. I would not try to combine them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I removed the namespace but it still does not find the Class :-(

Comment: Go for a simple Class definition, with standard PHP, include ... and new Class call. (In your file, you have also added "use stdClass"?)

Comment: Ah, I removed the namespace and the use stdClass and now it works :-) Thank you very much!